# Bash script with global exec redirection doesn't behave the same as root

Tags: bash, shell, root, sudo, io-redirection

I'm writing a script in which I want all output (stdout & stderr) to be displayed in my terminal as well as redirected into a log file. Here is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exec &> >(tee -a main.log)

case $1 in
    "start")
    echo "Starting some services..."
    ;;
    "status")
    echo "inactive"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start | status" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Now here is an example session of me testing the script:

```
$ ./main.sh status
$ inactive

$ sudo ./main.sh status
$ cat main.log
inactive
inactive
```

We can notice:

- When executed as a non-root user, the output is displayed after my prompt, which is already weird enough in my opinion.
- When executed as `root`, no output is displayed in my terminal.

  - But we do have `inactive` twice in the log file.

Can someone explain to me what's happening here? I would want the script to behave the same whether it's run as `root` or non-root user.

What's even more surprising to me is when I use the script with `bash -x`:

```
$ bash -x ./main.sh status
+ exec
++ tee -a main.log
$ + case $1 in
+ echo inactive
inactive

$ sudo bash -x ./main.sh status
+ exec
++ tee -a main.log
```

When run as `root`, the script just stops after `tee`.

EDIT: I noticed that when run with `bash -x`, the rest of the `-x` output is redirected to the file. So the script doesn't just stops after `tee`.

EDIT: Here's my `bash` version

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: `>(tee ...)` is running a separate process asynchronously. All the behavior you're surprised by is obvious when you understand that.

Comment: (And `&>` redirects stderr -- which is where `set -x` logs go -- as well as stdout, so your `set -x` logs become asynchronous too, thus, printed some time _after_ the actual event they're recording has already taken place).

Comment: If you want to avoid this, which specific version of bash are you targeting? If it's modern (later than 4.3 or 4.4 or so), process substitutions store the PID of the child process in `$!` so you can use `wait` to wait for that process to exit, making it possible to fix this. If you're using something older, fixes get really ugly and hacky (like running `tee` with a lock, and having your script close its stdout and stderr and block until it can grab that lock before it exits) and I have no interest in discussing them further than the brief reference already in this comment.

Comment: I edited the question with my `bash` version, I'm using `5.1.16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach 1: `wait`ing for a process expansion

Since you're using bash 5.x, you can collect the PID of a process expansion and `wait` for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec {orig_stdout}>&1 {orig_stderr}>&2
exec > >(tee -a main.log) 2>&1
log_pid=$!
cleanup() {
  if [[ $log_pid ]]; then # so we only run cleanup once; this lets it be explicitly called
    # restore our original stdout and stderr; closes the input to tee
    exec >&$orig_stdout 2>&$orig_stderr
    # since tee's input has closed, it will exit; wait for that to happen
    wait "$log_pid"
    # clear the variable for that PID so if we run cleanup again it's a noop
    unset log_pid
  fi
}
trap cleanup EXIT

# ...rest of your script goes here

cleanup # in theory unnecessary because of the trap, but legal.
```

---

#### Approach 2: Re-exec'ing yourself... but safely

This is what the preexisting answer does, but in a manner more cautious to be correct and secure

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $forked ]]; then
  forked=1 exec -a "$0" bash "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@" | tee -a main.log
  exit
fi

# ...rest of your script goes here
```

(`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is more reliable than `$0` as described in [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)).

Comment: With `Approach 2`, the script outputs twice every time. I believe it is because of the pipe: the script doesn't seem to end after `exec`. I solved it by adding `exit $?`, but I think it's weird since the intent of using `exec` was not to do that :-/

Comment: Best I found was this:
`cmd=$(cat << EOF
forked=1 exec -a "$0" bash "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$@" |& tee -a main.log
EOF
       )
exec bash -c "$cmd"`

Comment: @Unda, FYI, `exit $?` is the default behavior of `exit` with no arguments. But that's a good point; I'll add the explicit exit to the answer. That said, `<<EOF` there causes security bugs because it's substituting data into code (heredocs perform variable expansions; `$0`, `$@`, &c get replaced with the associated values, unless you use `<<'EOF'` instead).

Answer (score 0):

I believe a found a good enough trick, we can make the script re-run itself with the needed redirections:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ "$forked" != 'true' ]; then
    exec bash -c "env - forked=true $0 $@ |& tee -a main.log"
fi


case $1 in
    "start")
    echo $(date --iso-8601=seconds): "Starting some services..."
    ;;
    "status")
    echo "inactive"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 start | status" 1>&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: There are serious security problems here. Expanding `$@` inside a string does not at all work the same way as expanding the literal argument list.

Comment: Try passing command-line arguments with spaces -- you'll see your command be corrupted. You're also effectively `eval`ing content that was previously data; an argument of `'$(rm -rf ~)'` will cause `rm` to literally be run.

Comment: (well, in practice you won't get that specific command triggering a vulnerability because `$(rm -rf ~)` has spaces in it so it'll trigger `$@` splitting your `-c` argument into distinct words so everything past the first word doesn't run; but `'$(/tmp/evil)'` has no spaces, and will run a script `/tmp/evil`, and someone could put `rm -rf ~` _in there_; substitute running a reverse proxy / rootkit / etc to taste)